# Reactive pipeline with ComletableFuture, timeout, backpressure

Tags: java, reactive-programming, project-reactor

I have an app that publishes messages. Data comes from some source (doesn't matter in this case) and when we publish we get a java CompletableFuture back.
I also have special messages - beginning and ending of a batch.

What I want to implement is a pipeline that has several properties:

- we can record how long it took to get the CompletableFuture to complete
- we can timeout if the future didn't complete in time
- in case there is an error on the Future or there is a timeout - report an error
- have backpressure implemented, don't have too many CompletableFutures in flight
- record total time it took for the whole batch to complete

I had a different messaging infrastructure before and didn't get a future back, but just could push a message to another service and I have the implementation for that:

I have a sink to which I push a collection of objects to be published:

```
public void push(Collection<DataEnvelope> envelopes) {
    sink.emitNext(envelopes, this::onEmitFailure);
}
```

then I get the flux from the sink:

```
mainFlux = sink.asFlux()
            .filter(this::checkForEmptyDataEnvelopeCollection)
            .flatMap(Flux::fromIterable);

            .filter(this::checkForNullDataEnvelope)
            .filter(this::checkForBeginningOfStreamEnvelope)
            .filter(this::checkForEndOfStreamEnvelope);

            .map(mainPublisher::publish) // this is where I can get CompletableFuture, I can store it in the Envelope object I publish
            .retryWhen(Retry.backoff(pipelineConfig.getErrorRetryTimes(),
Duration.of(pipelineConfig.getErrorRetrySeconds(), ChronoUnit.SECONDS)))
// I want to retry if timeout to complete CompletableFuture expired
            .onErrorContinue(errorPipeline::push) 
            .map(envelope -> {
                this.timedLogger.incrementLogItemCount(envelope.getLoggerKey());
                return envelope;
            });

           mainFlux.subscribe(pipelineStatusReporter::completed);
```

I wonder how do I convert this to take CompletableFuture into account and how to do backpressure.
Say, only have N messages in flight and also if timeout on the future completion expires push the message to error pipeline.

Comment: if you want to apply a timeout, you can use `.orTimeout(timeout, timeunit)` as for handling errors/exceptions use `.exceptionally(function)` (or any of the async versions).  So you would map `.map(e-> mainPublisher.publish(e).orTimeout(...).exceptionally(...))`

Comment: my publish method is non blocking, I send a publish of my object and get a future back. 
When the future finishes I want to inspect the results of it - if it succeeded. If the future is not complete within the timeout or errors I want to error out (push my payload on error Flux).

Comment: you can use `thenAccept()`, `thenApply()` or `whenComplete()` or their async counterparts to access the results of the completed future